# git makes my sshfs busy

Tags: macos, git, sshfs

I have sshfs running on mac and I want to unmount it, however it says that resource is busy. `sudo lsof | grep /path/to/sshfs` shows two git entries: one CWD entry in the root of sshfs (there is a git repository) and one REG read access file descriptor for `.git/refs/remotes/origin/master`. I have no terminals running any git operations at the moment. Is it safe to kill git now and what's the best way to do it?

Comment: The interesting question is: What application are you running that uses git in the first place? (Your `lsof` output should tell you, if you leave out the grep and look at the parent PID). You should probably close that application first. Commandline `git` should never leave running git processes.

Comment: @dirkt the problem resolved itself when left for around half an hour, git entries disappeared from lsof and I was able to umount sshfs. Thanks for the tip though, I will look at parent process next time that happens

Comment: @dirkt I am facing the same problem now, parent pid of that git process is 1 (so it's launchd)

Comment: Interesting. This could also mean that the original parent process died and didn't wait to collect all children, so the child(ren) were moved to PID 1 as parent. Which means it's a bug in whatever that process is. Do you use any software that starts git processes?

Comment: @dirkt I suspect that this could be visual studio code, that's really the only thing I'm using to work on that folder